# How to change the text from buttons in woocommerce mini cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, gettext

I'm trying to change the 'View cart' and "Checkout" buttons text in WooCommerce mini cart and make it "request quote" and maybe remove the 'view cart' button.

I tried a lot of solutions, first with CSS I tried to hide it or change the content attribute, and I tried the following:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translated_text ) {
    if ( 'View cart' === $translated_text ) {
        $translated_text = 'Your new text here';
    }
    return $translated_text;
} );
```

But it seems none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code. Try the following instead *(emptying your cart first)*:

```php
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translated_text, $original_text, $domain ) {
    // Not in cart or checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        return $translated_text;
    }

    if ( 'View cart' === $original_text ) {
        $translated_text = 'Your new cart text';
    } 
    if ( 'Checkout' === $original_text ) {
        $translated_text = 'Your new chackout text';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

To remove mini cart "View cart" button, use:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', function(){
    // Removing Button
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_button_view_cart', 10 );
}, 1 );
```

To remove mini cart "Checkout" button, use:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', function(){
    // Removing Button
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons', 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
}, 1 );
```

To customize mini cart buttons, see [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310525/change-cart-and-checkout-button-links-on-woocommerce-mini-cart-widget/46311421#46311421)

**Note:** Always empty your cart, to refresh mini cart persistent display.